# Using async/await and returning Task<HttpResponseMessage> From ASP.NET Web API Methods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a Portable Class Library (PCL) method like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetLineStatuses()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        return response.GetResponseStream().ReadAllText();
    }
}
```

My ASP.NET Web Api method looks like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    string statuses = await service.GetStatuses();
    response.Content = new StringContent(statuses);
    return response;
}
```

What are the implications of returning a Task in Web API. Is this allowed? The only reason I want to use await is so I can use a Portable Class Library (PCL). What is the best practice? Should I have a syncronous version of my method and an asyncronous version? What are the performance and code readability and maintainability implications?

Also would I have the same effect if I returned `Task<string>` rather than `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`?

Comment: I belive ASP.NET in .Net 4.5 does support `async` methods, so your code should work fin. Why are you asking if this is allowed? Didn't you try it out?

Comment: I also want to know what the performance and code readability and maintainability implications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async and await are perfectly acceptable in ASP.NET. Here's a Scott Handselman video demoing it: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/async-and-await

"Also would I have the same effect if I returned `Task<string>` rather than `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`?"

Not really sure what you mean by this. The Task is like a container for the object, so a `Task<string>` would contain your string result and a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` would contain your HttpResponseMessage result... Is that what you mean? I think either method is perfectly acceptable. If you just need the string, then go with that. No point in returning more than you need.

Comment: In Web API, you can return any object you want to be serialized as the content or return a HttpResponseMessage. Thats what I meant.

Comment: I'm still not following you. Keep in mind, it's not returning a string, but a Task<string>. The string, in Task<string>.Result can be rendered as content, but a Task<string> itself cannot.

Comment: Returning a string and returning an HttpResponseMessage with a StringContent and two different things. If you return a string, WebAPi will use content negotiation to find a formatter that can serialize that string. If you return a StringContent, that string goes out directly in the response. But returning a Task<string> that completes eventually with a string should be equivalent to returning that string directly as far as WebAPI is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

as alternative:

```
public static async Task<string> CallGET(string requestUri, string id = "")
{
    string responseData;
    using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        Uri.TryCreate(new Uri(baseURI), $"{requestUri}{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? string.Empty : $"/{id}")}", out Uri fullRequestUri);
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(fullRequestUri))
        {
            responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return responseData;
    }
}
```

and call would be:

```
var getListUsersResult = Utils.CallGET($"/v1/users").Result;
var resultset= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(getListUsersResult, typeof(List<UsersDTO>)) as List<UsersDTO>;
UserDTO r = users.Where(d => d.Name.ToLower().Contains("test")).FirstOrDefault();
```

and another call for one item:

```
var getUser = Utils.CallGET($"/v1/users", $"{USER_ID}").Result;
var getUserResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(getUser, typeof(UserDTO)) as UserDTO;
```