# Can I get rid of this horrible blocking code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, blocking

I need some help, In a web api service call, I need to call a function in a dll that executes asynchronously, and then gives the response in a call back function. Now normally this would be good , but now with a web api the idea is to execute the command and then return the response.

Below is my current code which works, but I think its terrible code, its everything you don't want to do. Especially on a web server when this code is going to run for every request.

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Off(string id)
    {
        APNLink.Link link = LinkProvider.getDeviceLink(id, User.Identity.Name);

        if (link.LinkConnectionStatus == APNLink.ConnectionStatus.Connected)
        {
            link.RelayCommand(APNLink.RelayNumber.Relay1, APNLink.RelayCommand.OFF, test);
            BlockForResponse();
            var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return msg;
        }
        else
        {
            if (link.Connect())
            {
                var status = link.LinkConnectionStatus;
                int timeout = 0;
                while (status != APNLink.ConnectionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    status = link.LinkConnectionStatus;
                    if (status == APNLink.ConnectionStatus.Connected)
                    {
                        break;
                    }                        
                    if (timeout++ > 16)
                    {
                        var msg1 = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout);
                        return msg1;
                    }
                }
                link.RelayCommand(APNLink.RelayNumber.Relay1, APNLink.RelayCommand.OFF, test);
                BlockForResponse();
                var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                return msg;
            }
            else
            {
                var msg2 = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                return msg2;
            }
        }

    }

    bool flag = false;

    public void test(bool var)
    {
    flag = true;
    }

     private static bool BlockForResponse()
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (!flag)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            if (count > 10)
            {
                //timeout
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

now the thing is I have to block when waiting for the dll, Connection to be connected, only then can I execute the command. once I have executed the command. I then have to block again for the response.

Another aspect is, Can I actually block on an asp.net thread? Surely each request is not handled on its own thread?

Is there any way I can make this code neater and most importantly more efficient?

Comment: Questions about improving code should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does your api provide any asynchronous version of `RelayCommand`, i.e `BeginRelayCommand`?

Comment: The return signature has to change to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068515/using-async-await-and-returning-taskhttpresponsemessage-from-asp-net-web-api-m

Comment: @NedStoyanov The api is asynchronous, it just calls a callback when its done.  But sadly it only provides what's in the example. BUt if there is something that will make a big difference I can request that they add that functionality to the dll

Comment: My bad, i am an idiot. You can use a `TaskCompletionSource` see @Noseratio's response below

Comment: How to get rid of this horrible blocking code? As a mentor once told me about how he fixed problems in my code: "Shift-PgDn-PgDn, Del"

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question:

> In a web api service call, I need to call a function in a dll that
>   executes asynchronously, and then gives the response in a call back
>   function.

IMO, the best way of doing this is to make your controller method asynchronous and use `TaskCompletionSource` to wrap the callback of your DLL. Some good additional reads:

- [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).
- [The Nature of `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx?Redirected=true).

The code may look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Off(string id)
{
    APNLink.Link link = LinkProvider.getDeviceLink(id, User.Identity.Name);

    if (link.LinkConnectionStatus == APNLink.ConnectionStatus.Connected)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        CallbackType test = delegate {           
           tcs.SetResult(null);
        };

        link.RelayCommand(
            APNLink.RelayNumber.Relay1, 
            APNLink.RelayCommand.OFF,
            test);

        // BlockForResponse();
        await tcs.Task; // non-blocking

        var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return msg;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Busy Reading the links you provided. They are great. Exactly what I am looking for as my calls to the dll can take up to 10 seconds to execute. So I definitely think I need to use async methods.

Comment: @Zapnologica, make sure to read [some other links](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info), especially [about how `AspNetSynchronizationContext` works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).